# Migrating large amount of data physically through disks over international borders

Tags: migration

I am not sure whether this is the right place to ask. We are moving some of our QA environments from the USA to our office in India. New servers that will be deployed in India will need to be loaded with Terabytes of data from the US. Transferring it over the internet will take weeks or months, so we are planning to load the data in a few large hard-drives and physically bringing it to India through Fedex/UPS. However, we are unsure of the legal formalities. Could someone provide a lead on the legal technicalities of sending such a good international borders, if there are any.

Comment: Glad you asked on here but you *need* to get formal legal support on this sorry, nobody here will be able to give you a binding answer. That said once you do find out perhaps you could update this question with the answer and I'm sure many would find the answer interesting.